# Make <a> inside jQuery autocomplete clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, click

I managed to add a link to the right of the jQuery autocomplete items, using the following code:

```
function onClientSelect(event, ui) {
    // My handling code goes here
    event.preventDefault();
}

$("#mypage input[name='client']").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    appendTo: $(this).parent(),
    source: '/filter_client/',
    select: onClientSelect,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

My server returns element label in this format:

```
<div class="ac-item-lb">My Item Label</div>
<a class="ac-item-a" href="/url_to_go_to/" target="_blank">View Detail</a>
```

What I want to do is to open the link in a new tab when I click on 'View Detail', which clicking any other area executes onClientSelect just like normal. However, currently left-clicking on the link also executes `onClientSelect`. The only way to open the link is to click the middle wheel or right mouse button and select 'open in new tab'.

I tried attaching a click event handler on the link with event.stopImmediatePropagation() but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: no one knows this???

Comment: Are you using jQuery autocomplete or some other autocomplete plugin

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with using an array instead of responses from server?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way to do it is by defining a custom `select` function and by not using an `<a>` for the links

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

JS:

```
 var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var elem = $(event.originalEvent.toElement);
        if (elem.hasClass('ac-item-a')) {
            var url = elem.attr('data-url');
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open(url, '_blank ');
        }
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append('<a>' + item.label + '<span class="ac-item-a" data-url="http://www.nba.com"> View Details</span></a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/jkukvpgo/3/).

Comment: Great solution - could use a bit more CSS styling to clarify what's going on here. I'll recommend that you edit the JSFiddle to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/jkukvpgo/3/

Comment: @sqsinger - Thank you for the styling, I've edited the answer and added your fiddle.

Comment: Good thinking, but why don't you let native elements do their thing. Just create a normal hyperlink. No hacks, and is accessible to assistive technologies: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/jkukvpgo/6/

Comment: @RyanWheale - since a click on the hyperlink will select the current item and that's what he wanted to prevent.

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about putting a conditional in your click handler to **not** `preventDefault` when it is that link? If you test if the element should function as normal then you can `return` early before the `preventDefault` and then the link should function as normal.

Here is an example ([JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/qulucu/)):

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
  // If the target element has the class `test-clickable` then the
  // function will return early, before `preventDefault`.
  if (this.className.indexOf('test-clickable') !== -1) {
    return;
  }

  alert('That link is not clickable because of `preventDefault`');
  
  e.preventDefault();
}

$('a').click(clickHandler);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
a:after {
  content: ' [class=' attr(class)']';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a class='test-clickable' href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Link</a>
  <a class='test-not-clickable' href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Amir,  regarding to your answer, I think that opening window inside javascript function from **select** event can be blocked by PopupBlocker

pinghsien422 , your server side should return Json and not complete html , if you must return complete html, make the following changes:

1.Remove the clientSelect function

2.No 'a' tag is needed in renderData function

```
 $("#mypage input[name='client']").autocomplete({
   minLength: 1,
  appendTo: $(this).parent(),
   source: '/filter_client/',
  focus: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append( item.label )
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, jquery's event takes precedence over your select event - no matter what you do, you can't stop anything there. But you can proxify menuselect event and then decide if it should be invoked ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev8dnxrh/2/)).

```
var ac = $("#mypage input[name='client']").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    appendTo: document.body,
    source: availableTags,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
}).data("ui-autocomplete");
ac._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<div>"+item.label+"<a class='link' href='http://test'>(http://test)</a></div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
var ms = $._data(ac.menu.element.get(0), 'events').menuselect[0].handler;
ac.menu.element.off("menuselect");
ac.menu.element.on("menuselect", function (ev) {
    if($(ev.originalEvent.target).hasClass("link"))
        return;
    ms.apply(this,arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `even.stopImmediatePropagation` in `onclick` binding to link. Page is opening and select handler not executed.

```
var li = $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append('<a class="ac-item-a" href="http://www.nba.com">' + item.label + '</a>')
    .appendTo(ul);

li.find('a').bind('click', function(event){ event.stopImmediatePropagation() });

return li;
```